# Is it possible to sort by a range in Elasticsearch?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, range

When I execute the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "my_value": "hi"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "my_range": {
              "gt": 0,
              "lte": 200
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "my_range": {
      "order": "asc",
      "mode": "min"
    }
  }
}
```

I get the error:

```
"caused_by": {
  "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason": "Fielddata is not supported on field [my_range] of type [long_range]"
}
```

How can I enable a `range` datatype to be sortable? Is this possible?

Elasticsearch version: 5.4, but I am wondering if this is possible with ANY version.

**More context**

Not all documents in the alias/index have the range field. However, the query filters to only include documents with that field.

Comment: What is index mappings?  did your close the "my_range" field docValues, what's your ES version?

Comment: Could you please post the output of GET <your_index_name>/_mapping  ?

Comment: @Lupanoide No, but the type mapping I want to sort on is `long_range`. An example of doing that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is sort based on the `difference of the range` coz I'm not sure if simply sorting on any of the range values would make any sense.

For e.g. if range for one document is `100, 300` and another `200, 600` then you would want to sort based on the difference for e.g. you would want the lesser range to be appearing i.e `300-100 = 200` to be appearing at the top.

If so, I've made use of the below [painless script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-examples.html) and implemented [script based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting).

### Sorting based on difference in Range

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "match_all":{  

      }
   },
   "sort":{  
      "_script":{  
         "type":"number",
         "script":{  
            "lang":"painless",
            "inline":"params._source.my_range.lte-params._source.my_range.gte"
         },
         "order":"asc"
      }
   }
}
```

Note that in this case, sort won't be based on any of the field values of `my_range` but only on their differences. If you want to further sort based on the fields like `lte`, `lt`, `gte` or `gt` you can have your sort implemented with multiple script as below:

### Sorting based on difference in Range + Range Field (my_range.lte)

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "match_all":{  

      }
   },
   "sort":[  
      {  
         "_script":{  
            "type":"number",
            "script":{  
               "lang":"painless",
               "inline":"params._source.my_range.lte - params._source.my_range.gte"
            },
            "order":"asc"
         }
      },
      {  
         "_script":{  
            "type":"number",
            "script":{  
               "lang":"painless",
               "inline":"params._source.my_range.lte"
            },
            "order":"asc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So in this case even if for two documents, ranges are same, the one with the lesser `my_range.lte` would be showing up first.

### Sort based on range field

However if you simply want to sort based on one of the range values, you can make use of below query.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "match_all":{  

      }
   },
   "sort":{  
      "_script":{  
         "type":"number",
         "script":{  
            "lang":"painless",
            "inline":"params._source.my_range.lte"
         },
         "order":"asc"
      }
   }
}
```

### Updated Answer to manage documents without range

This is for the scenario, ***Sort based on difference in range + Range.lte or Range.lt whichever is present***

The below code what it does is,

- Checks if the document has `my_range` field
- If it doesn't have, then by default it would return `Long.MAX_VALUE`. This would mean if you sort by asc, this document should returned
  last.
- Further it would check if document has `lte` or `lt` and uses that value as `high`. Note that default value of `high` is `Long.MAX_VALUE`.
- Similarly it would check if document has `gte` or `gt` and uses that value as `low`. Default value of `low` would be `0`.
- Calculate now `high - low` value on which sorting would be applied.

### Updated Query

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "size":100,
   "query":{  
      "match_all":{  

      }
   },
   "sort":[  
      {  
         "_script":{  
            "type":"number",
            "script":{  
               "lang":"painless",
               "inline":""" 
              if(params._source.my_range==null){ 
                return Long.MAX_VALUE; 
              } else { 

                long high = Long.MAX_VALUE; 
                long low = 0L; 

                if(params._source.my_range.lte!=null){ 
                  high = params._source.my_range.lte; 
                } else if(params._source.my_range.lt!=null){ 
                  high = params._source.my_range.lt; 
                } 

                if(params._source.my_range.gte!=null){ 
                  low = params._source.my_range.gte; 
                } else if (params._source.my_range.gt==null){ 
                  low = params._source.my_range.gt; 
                } 

              return high - low; 

              } 
                """
            },
            "order":"asc"
         }
      },
      {  
         "_script":{  
            "type":"number",
            "script":{  
               "lang":"painless",
               "inline":""" 
                if(params._source.my_range==null){ 
                  return Long.MAX_VALUE; 
                } 

                long high = Long.MAX_VALUE; 
                if(params._source.my_range.lte!=null){ 
                  high = params._source.my_range.lte; 
                } else if(params._source.my_range.lt!=null){ 
                  high = params._source.my_range.lt; 
                } 
                  return high;"""
            },
            "order":"asc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This should work with ES 5.4. Hope it helps!

Comment: This is close, thanks, but not all documents have the range field. I didn't expect that to make a difference but I'll update the question.

Comment: @MirroredFate Could you please check the answer now. I've updated it. Please see the section *Updated Answer to manage documents without range fields*. I've just provided explanation for the **first script** in that query. **Second script** is much similar and self explanatory once if you go through first script. Let me know if that is what is expected. The above query would work even if you do not apply filter on the range field in the query.

Comment: Thank you. I tried a much simpler variant, as I have a guarantee that if the range exists then it should be sorted by an existing `gte` value. So I used a very simple if/else where the else just returns the gte value. I was surprised that the documents returned were still not ordered by their `gte`value. Also, just to clarify, yes I *really* do want to sort documents by where their range starts. Currently I am doing this in code and honestly it is relatively performant because the set size is small enough, but it would be interesting to do it with ES.

Comment: Hey @MirroredFate The updated query I've provided would sort by `range` and then further sorts by their `lte`. All you would need to do to sort by `gte` or `gt` in the updated query is, simply replace `lte` with `gte` & `lt` with `gt` in the **second sort script** of the updated query I've provided. So if you have documents with equal ranges, the one with lesser `gte` or `gt` would be appearing at the top when using `"order": "asc"`. Keep in mind that documents which do not have `gte` or `gt` would appear at the last. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: hey @MirroredFate were you able to have this query resolved. If your solution is different from the answers posted here, would very much appreciate if you can post the answer or just the script logic and accept it so that it could be useful for others.

Comment: Hey Kamal, still no dice. I'm checking if the `my_range` is null and returning `MAX_VALUE` else returning `my_range.gte`, which will always exist. Still not sorted correctly.
So I assume something is wrong with my script in relation to how my docs exist, but not sure what that is.

Comment: @MirroredFate Strange. Let me do some testing on my end. I like to think it would work correctly but yes, I will test and let you know if I come up with something.

Answer (score 3):

It is not straight-forward to sort using a field of range data type. Still you can use [script based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) to some extent to get the expected result.

e.g. For simplicity of script I'm assuming for all your docs, the data indexed against `my_range` field has data for `gt` and `lte` only and you want to sort based on the minimum values of the two then you can add the below for sorting:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "my_value": "hi"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "my_range": {
              "gt": 0,
              "lte": 200
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "Math.min(params['_source']['my_range']['gt'], params['_source']['my_range']['lte'])"            
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

You can modify the script as per your needs for complex data involving combination of all `lt`, `gt`, `lte`, `gte`.

**Updates (Scripts for other different use cases):**

**1. Sort by difference**

```
"Math.abs(params['_source']['my_range']['gt'] - params['_source']['my_range']['lte'])"
```

**2. Sort by `gt`**

```
"params['_source']['my_range']['gt']"
```

**3. Sort by `lte`**

```
"params['_source']['my_range']['lte']"
```

**4. Sorting if query returns few docs which don't have `range` field**

```
"if(params['_source']['my_range'] != null) { <sorting logic> } else { return 0; }"
```

Replace `<sorting logic>` with the required logic of sorting (which can be one of the 3 above or the one in the query)

`return 0` can be replace by `return -1` or anything other number as per the sorting needs

Comment: Unfortunately, not all documents have the range field. I'll update the docs to reflect this.

Comment: In your query there is already a range filter, so the resulting documents will definitely have the range field.

Comment: This solution actually gives me another problem, `[script] unknown field [source], parser not found`.

Comment: You can change `source` to `inline` for it to work in ES 5.x. Post 6.x versions I think it won't give that error. Both `source` and `inline` would work.

Comment: Ahh Yes I didn't notice the ES version being used, for ES 5.x `inline` has to be used instead of `source`. Thanks @Kamal for pointing this out. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**This can be resolved easily by using the regex interval filter :**

> Interval The interval option enables the use of numeric ranges,
>   enclosed by angle brackets "<>". For string: "foo80":

```
foo<1-100>     # match
foo<01-100>    # match
foo<001-100>   # no match
Enabled with the INTERVAL or ALL flags.
```

[Elactic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "my_value": "hi"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "my_range": {
              "value": "<0-200>"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "my_range": {
      "order": "asc",
      "mode": "min"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Can only use regexp queries on keyword and text fields - not on [my_range] which is of type [long_range]`